# Not getting a valid json response

Tags: laravel

Hi i am trying to get the valid json response but i am not getting what i want my response is:

```
 {
"status": "true",
"message": "Data Found!",
"data": {
    "message_id": 25,
    "sender_id": 15,
    "body": "kaleem",
    "subject": "Test",
    "senderName": "Tester Techleadz",
    "created_at": "2016-06-23 00:46:55"
}
}
```

we can see the message_id and sender_id are not in quotes as other values are in quotes i want to get the message_id and sender_id in quotes as well 
My controller code is:

```
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $type = $request->input('type');

    if($type == 'trash'){
        $trash = MessagesRelationModel::leftjoin('messages','messages.id','=','messages_relation.message_id')
            ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','messages.sender_id')
            ->leftjoin('contacts','users.contacts_id','=','contacts.id')
            ->where('messages.id' , $id)
            ->select('messages_relation.message_id','messages.sender_id','messages.body','messages.subject',DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) As senderName'),'messages.created_at')
            ->first();

        if(count($trash) > 0)
        {
            $resultArray = ['status' => 'true', 'message' => 'Data Found!', 'data' => $trash];
            return Response::json( $resultArray, 200);
        }
    }
    else{
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'false', 'message' => 'No Data Found'];
        return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
}
```

how can i solve my problem in controller i used the select clause in controller any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: try to use json_encode() predefined function it will be work.

Comment: _Why_ do you want them in quotes? This is perfectly valid JSON already. / If you want them quoted, then make the values in the input be strings already, not integers.

Comment: Your question is wrongly worded. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check for validity and use [JSON Viewer](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to check if valid and view structure.

Answer (score -1):

This is a valid json, message_id and sender_id are integers, so that the are not in quoted, You can use them easily...